# how to open default document chooser in android without images and videos

Tags: android

I am trying to open Default Document chooser Activity in Android.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 intent.setType("*/*");
 startActivityForResult(intent, 7);
```

But i don't want images and videos to be part of this.How to remove images and videos from list.

Comment: if you are trying to use doc file format use this `intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/*");` its worked for me..

Comment: I want to exclude images and videos from list.Right now using intent.setType("application/*");Not sure how much correct it is.

Comment: try to use `"text/*"` insted of `"application/*"`

Comment: Please refer this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29021091/7166151